# how can i get list of models from ajax to controller?

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an apicontroller that returns List to success part of ajax function:

```
var inputdata = {
        'InsPayInsuranceID': insPayInsuranceID
         , 'InstallmentDistance': installmentDistance
         , 'InsPayNumber': insPayNumber
         , 'InsPayFirstInstallmentDate': insPayFirstInstallmentDate
         , 'HasInsPayWitTax': insInsPayWitTax
         , 'InsPayRatio': (insPayRatio > 0) ? insPayRatio : 0
    }

  $.ajax({
        url: '/api/InstallmentApi',
        type: 'Get',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional:true,
        data: inputdata,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#GridPan").load('@Url.Action("ReturnMyPartial", "Insurance")', result);
        }
```

When "ReturnMYPartial" is called in success part of ajax and is sent "result"(return List from apicontroller to ajax) to it, the argument of "ReturnMyPartial" is null!

how can i solve it and get List ?

"ReturnMyPartial" controller:

```
 public ActionResult ReturnMyPartial(List<INS_InsPaymenttDetails> myIns)//int InsuranceID , string MyInsNO) 
    {
       //// Some Codes...

        return PartialView("_MyPartial", myIns);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from this ajax call there is a middle piece that you haven't included.  I don't know what InstallmentApi does.  That is the method your ajax call is making a call to and result being empty will be from there.  I would try rewriting things like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ReturnMyPartial", "Insurance")',
    type: 'Get',
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional:true,
    data: inputdata,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#GridPan").load(result); //I use .html but looking up .load this should work also
    }
})
```

your controller would then take input parameters that match Inputdata

```
public PartialViewResult ReturnMyPartial(string InsPayInsuranceID, etc)
```

and on the controller you can call InstallmentApi to get the list and pass it through to the partial

```
var myIns = InstallmentApi(parameters);
return PartialView("_MyPartial", myIns);
```